How to fix Mac with faulty drive: invalid sibling link
My wife inherited her sister’s Mac A1225. It has been in storage for the last couple of years. I’ve been asked to retrieve the family photos but is doesn’t boot up.
Apple logo shows. Progression bar shows but only for the first couple of bars then stays cycling or goes to blue or grey screen.
I tried PRAM rest (option, command, P, R) and
Disk utility on start up but the utility option doesn’t show.
I’ve tried making a bootable usb but that was a task in its own…I don’t think I created right, will try again.
Using verbose mode gives me the attached results.
Any suggestions on how I could recover the photos?
Edit: I was able to create a bootable usb. I can boot up to the usb but the only options given is to install the OS to the computer. If I do that, won’t it write over/wipe out the photos on the drive? I was hoping to boot up from the usb then run disk utilities in an attempt to fix the drive or at least copy files from it.
Thanks

This iMac is from 2008/9 and is rather ancient, as Macs go. You have few options: 1/ find a working Mac with Firewire 800 ports and attempt to access the damaged HDD in Target Disk mode. Copy over all the files you can. 2/ Have the data recovered by a data recovery company. This will mean opening up the iMac and removing the drive. If these pictures are important, (and family photos are always important,) it may be worth the cost.

Thanks for your input Daemon.
I’ve not been able to find a way to get the old Mac into Target mode because I’m not able to boot it. I was able to make a bootable usb. The computer will boot to the usb but then it wants to install the OS to the computer (which I don’t want to in case it over writes/wipes data). I had hopes that I could boot to the usb then be able to run disk utilities on the damaged drive.

You need a second working computer with Firewire 800 ports to mount the damaged HD in Target Disk mode. Perhaps you can use the bootable USB key to install macOS onto an external SSD drive, and boot the SSD.
